# Can Select() be used to detect and identify multiple stream input

Tags: c, unix, io, serial-port

I have just come across the `select()` function for linux (or is it Unix?) OS's. And its looking like it can achieve what I need to do.

I have a Linux process (on Debian) that has IPC (Inter-Process Communication) between 3 other processes. 2 of them are Serial Ports Streams and the other is a Named Pipe.

My process needs to read data from each of these streams and react accordingly (its a proxy between these 3 processes). Theres no order to the data coming in from each process (one may talk, then another lay silent for a while).

So I am thinking of having a main loop that simply uses `select()` to listen on all streams (with a timeout of never). That way select can notify me when/if a stream writes to my process, which stream is talking and then I can react accordingly.

Is this how select works? Is this design ok and how you would handle 3 streams where their behaviour is dynamic and not predictable (in terms of when they will write data to a stream)?

Comment: Yup, this is exactly the type of problem `select()` is meant to solve. It's a less messy (and more efficient, if the number of sources is large) alternative to multiple processes/threads and non-blocking I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what `select` is designed to do: multiplex multiple input streams and detect which have data ready to be read from.